# Solve : JAVA Selenium : Impossible to set a value on input

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to set a value to an input i try :

```
find(By.xpath("MyXpath")).type(montant);
```

and

```
find(By.xpath("MyXpath")).typeAndTab(montant) ;
```

and

```
find(By.xpath("MyXpath")).typeAndEnter(montant) ;
```

and

```
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("MyXpath")).sendKeys("value", "5");
```

and

```
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("MyXpath")).sendKeys(Keys.HOME,Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.END),"5");
```

and

```
Actions actionInput = new Actions(getDriver());
     actionInput.moveToElement(find(By.xpath("MyXpath"))).clickAndHold().sendKeys(montant).
     release().build().perform();
```

and

```
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("MyXpath")).click() ;
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("MyXpath")).clear() ;
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("MyXpath")).sendKeys(Keys.HOME,Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.END),"5");
```

nothing work..

but i can't set the value of the input the field is empty when i clear so it's not my xpath and i don't have error at this moment, the test continue the rest of the test normally but the result at the end it's not good because this field is not set to the good value :/

Anyone have an idea ?

the input :

```
<input class="MyClass" input-number="" type="number" value="valAngular" min="0" max="100" xpath="1">
```

the value is set with Angular 
is it a problem ?

thanks for your help !

Edit : I look developers of the website and it's solve, the angular property set in DOM block serenity

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. All of your code attempts are using some custom functions that we don't have access to so we don't know what is in them. You also haven't included any of your actual XPaths. Do something simple like `driver.findElement(...).sendKeys("abc");` and post the result. A link to the page would likely solve the problem. I don't see anything on that `INPUT` that would prevent normal behavior... are you sure that's the right `INPUT` and that your locator is good?

Comment: I can't put the code here because i'm developper for a company and it is an internal software, Therefore i can't put real Xpath, it's the good locator because the clear() function work

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver driver; // Assigned elsewhere
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementByClassName('MyClass').setAttribute('value', '10')");